# Rethrowing typed exception in C++ or C++11

Tags: c++, design-patterns, exception, c++11

I need to write a wrapper to a function. Its purpose is to cache the result and possibly exceptions of the function. It should work as follows: during the first execution it should execute the function and store the result (or exception) returned by the function. During next executions it should return previously stored result or rethrow caught exception.

The problem is, that I want to store the type of exception. So basically I want to catch every type of exception, and rethrow it in the future without losing its type.

I'm using C++ or C++11, so any solution in one of these languages would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it is doable in full generality. I would suppose the exceptions have a common superclass (or type, usually `std::exception`) and make it a template argument.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for `std::exception_ptr`.

You can get the currently-caught exception using `std::current_exception()`, store the resulting `std::exception_ptr`, and throw it later with `std::rethrow_exception(std::exception_ptr)`

There is a good example of usage on [the cppreference wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr).

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting. Do you know how it works internally? Is it possible to get this result without using std::exception_ptr?

Comment: @danilo2: Yes, but not portable. The exact mechanism is up to the particular implementation of the compiler and standard library you are using, which generally elect a particular ABI (like the Itanium ABI used by gcc and clang, among others). You can use the internal ABI mechanisms, but it will only work for implementations based on that ABI. Also, in earlier versions of C++, it is not sure that the ABI will allow everything that the Standard now asks for. `std::exception_ptr` (and all the related machinery) has been introduced in C++11 precisely to cover this gap and offer a uniform interface

Comment: @danilo2 Some of the functionality is borrowed from Boost.Exception, so you can use that instead. (As a library solution though, be warned that it simply cannot have the same capabilities as a language feature.)

Answer (score 0):

exception_ptr from VC++ is using RaiseException